# How to handle exception in Arcobject 'Attempted to read or write protected memory' while working with three different featureclass

Tags: arcobjects

I have three featureclasses representing Road,Rail and city junction respectively.
First i have taken rail  and road featureclass and done spatial query

```
spatialfilter.spatialrel=esrispatialrelenum.esrispatialrelintersects.
```

and found those roads from road featureclass that intersects rail network on the basis of some attribute.Then from intersected road , taken 'frm_Junction' field and open junction feature class and done query and found those junction point that has 'JUNCTION_ID = frm_Junction' of road and if record found in junction then 'RLY_Phatak' attribute value  is checked .if its zero then it is reported as error.

All the queries and function is running fine on one system but on another system exception prompt that is -- error: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory.This is often an indication that the other memory is corrupt'.

All the featurecursor and other memories are released properly still exception exists.

I am not getting why this exception is prompting when the code is working fine on three or four system.??How do we handle such type of exception??